# error: Object #<Object> has no method 'easeInOutCubic' - jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm having little trouble with easeInOutCubic.

I want to use jquery switchButton plugin: http://olance.github.io/jQuery-switchButton/ inside wordpress admin panel.

I've included code correctly, and I'm also positive I've jquery-ui core.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/test/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&amp;load%5B%5D=admin-bar,hoverIntent,common,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-tabs,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-slider,jquery-ui-button&amp;ver=3.5.2'></script>
```

I thought easeInOutCubic was part of jquery-ui core. Or not? Does wordpress have it included or do I've to include it manually? Any ideas?

S.

Comment: easing effects are part of jquery-UI effects core: http://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: you miss the easing library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, easing is not included in jquery-ui-core. It must be enabled separately.

```
wp_enqueue_script("jquery-effects-core");
```

Code above did the trick.

Comment: oops don't see your answer before i posted comment

Comment: @Neikos yep, in two days :)